# WiX 3.11.1 -- error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file

Tags: wix, windows-installer

WiX 3.11.1 on Windows 10 Pro Version 1703 64-bit. NOT using Visual Studio. Using simple text files as follows.

Here is a test case of the situation I am finding.

myapp.wxs is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">

    <Product Id="*"
             Name="MyApp"
             Language="1033"
             Version="1.0.0.0"
             Manufacturer="Me"
             UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE">

        <Package InstallerVersion="301"
                 Compressed="yes"
                 InstallScope="perMachine"
                 Manufacturer="Me"
                 Description="My App"
                 Keywords=".NET,Installer,MSI" />

        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />

        <!-- ****************************************** -->
        <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp"
                     Value="[CMP_Refresh_file]" />
        <!-- ****************************************** -->

        <Feature Id="MyFeature"
                 Title="MyApp Feature"
                 Description="Installs MyApp"
                 Level="1">
        </Feature>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="TestFolder" Name="TESTfolder" />
        </Directory>
        <Component Id="CMP_Refresh_file" Guid="*" Directory="TESTfolder">
            <File Id="FILE_RefreshPNG" Source= "Refresh.png" KeyPath="yes" />
        </Component>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

myapp.bat is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\candle.exe" myapp.wxs
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\light.exe"  myapp.wixobj -ext WixUIExtension -ext WixUtilExtension
@pause
```

When I run the .bat file, it cannot find the CMP_Refresh_file (error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file). The folder TESTfolder is a direct sub-folder of the folder in which the .wxs file exists.

Substituting the full file path solves the issue. BUT that is not what I want as I will have a multitude of files and folders. (Also, if I put the file in the same folder as the .wxs file, of course, it finds it.)

I suspect it is purely a syntactic issue caused by my ignorance. In any case, I have tried endless variations of syntax for the Value of WixUIDialogBmp without joy (except the full name).

Help to resolve **very** much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your WiX code I can see that you are getting confused between the MSI destination and the source folder paths. The Directory tag is to create a folder on the machine where you run the MSI (where you want to deploy your application)  - it has nothing to do with the source folders from where you package your files.

Replace your filepath with:

```
<File Id="FILE_RefreshPNG" Source= "\TESTfolder\Refresh.png" KeyPath="yes"/>
```

As you can see, the file -> source attribute path should be written with reference to your WXS file path.

If you are planning to deploy the refresh.png underneath the testfolder on the client machines then you got to move to closing `</Directory>` tag right after your `<File>` tag

Comment: Yes! You are right, Isaiah4110. That is also one possibility I thought of. Thank you. In fact, I have a completely separate source folder tree structure under AppDataFolder. I wanted to define a directory structure I could refer to by symbol for that and wrongly assumed the structure I created would refer to it also. Given that the source and destination structures will be identical, I (wrongly) assumed one could use the same structure and that the context would understand if it were source or destination. Can you offer a recommended approach?

Comment: Create the folder structure with all the files in it - then use wix heat to harvest it. http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html
I usually a tool called wixedit - and do the same thing. It will generate the wix script for you. Then you can modify it by hand to change the source paths manually.

Comment: please mark this as the answer if it helped you. thanks!

Comment: Many thanks again, Isaiah4110. I did mark the answer as correct ... but I am lowly on the Reputation scale so it did not increment. Apologies.

Comment: I also am now striking another interesting situation. I can now find the source files (thanks!). But I now receive the following types of errors/warnings:  

    error LGHT0204 : ICE38: Component CMP_Textfile installs to user profile. It must use a registry key under HKCU as its KeyPath, not a file.
    error LGHT0204 : ICE64: The directory DIR_TextFolder is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table.
    warning LGHT1076 : ICE91: The file 'FILE_Textfile' will be installed to the per user directory 'DIR_TextFolder' ...

Answer (score 0):

Try `<WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="[#CMP_Refresh_file]" />` which references the installed path. See [Formatted Strings](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/formatted-strings/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this while trying to figure out a different issue with source file resolution. [Isaiah4110's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48345207/2293142) is misleading. The `<Directory>` structure *can* specify both the destination on the target machine *and* where to find the source files as long as the directory structure is the same. You just have to nest your `<Component>` elements within the corresponding directory elements and specify the `Name` attribute rather than `Source`.

In this case, the following should work:

```xml
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="TestFolder" Name="TESTfolder">
        <Component Id="CMP_Refresh_file" Guid="*">
            <File Id="FILE_RefreshPNG" Name="Refresh.png" KeyPath="yes" />
        </Component>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

This works because the `Source` of a `<File>` defaults to the source path of the `<Component>`'s parent `<Directory>` element (if there is one) plus the `Name`. See: [File element reference](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/file.html) and [How to specify source files](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/specifying_source_files.html). Unfortunately this logic does not seem to work when placing the `<Component>` outside of the `<Directory>` structure as the example in the question does.