# jpackage on Windows: The system cannot find file, error 103

Tags: scala, wix, scalafx, jpackage

I am trying to package a ScalaFx app I built using jpackage and having trouble on windows (mac & linux work just fine).

I am building a fat jar using `sbt assembly` and then using `jpackage` to create a `.msi` however I am getting this error:

```sh
$ jpackage --win-shortcut --name krystalbull --app-version 0.1 --type msi -i target/scala-2.13/ --main-class com.krystal.bull.gui.GUI --main-jar krystal-bull-assembly-0.1.jar --icon src/main/resources/icons/krystal_bull.ico --verbose

  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
  env:
    pkg-assembly: krystal-bull-assembly-0.1.jar
    pkg-name: krystalbull
    pkg-version: 0.1
    JAVA_HOME_16.0.1_x64: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\jdk\16.0.1\x64
    JAVA_HOME: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\jdk\16.0.1\x64
    JAVA_HOME_16_0_1_X64: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\jdk\16.0.1\x64
[21:10:32.469] Running candle.exe
[21:10:32.541] Running C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\candle.exe
[21:10:34.005] Running light.exe
[21:10:34.024] Running C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\light.exe
[21:10:35.848] Detected [light.exe] version [3.11.2.4516].
[21:10:35.848] Detected [candle.exe] version [3.11.2.4516].
[21:10:35.849] WiX 3.11.2.4516 detected. Enabling advanced cleanup action.
[21:10:46.540] Command:
    jlink --output C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\runtime --module-path C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\jdk\\16.0.1\\x64\\jmods --add-modules jdk.management.jfr,java.rmi,jdk.jdi,jdk.charsets,jdk.xml.dom,java.xml,java.datatransfer,jdk.jstatd,jdk.httpserver,java.desktop,java.security.sasl,jdk.zipfs,java.base,jdk.crypto.ec,jdk.javadoc,jdk.management.agent,jdk.jshell,jdk.editpad,jdk.jsobject,java.sql.rowset,jdk.sctp,jdk.jlink,jdk.unsupported,java.smartcardio,java.security.jgss,java.compiler,jdk.nio.mapmode,jdk.dynalink,jdk.unsupported.desktop,jdk.accessibility,jdk.security.jgss,java.sql,jdk.incubator.vector,java.xml.crypto,java.logging,java.transaction.xa,jdk.jfr,jdk.crypto.cryptoki,jdk.net,java.naming,jdk.internal.ed,java.prefs,java.net.http,jdk.compiler,jdk.naming.rmi,jdk.internal.opt,jdk.jconsole,jdk.attach,jdk.crypto.mscapi,jdk.internal.le,java.management,jdk.jdwp.agent,jdk.internal.jvmstat,jdk.incubator.foreign,java.instrument,jdk.management,jdk.security.auth,java.scripting,jdk.jdeps,jdk.jartool,jdk.jpackage,java.management.rmi,jdk.naming.dns,jdk.localedata --strip-native-commands --strip-debug --no-man-pages --no-header-files
[21:10:46.540] Output:
    WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.vector, jdk.incubator.foreign

[21:10:46.544] Returned: 0

 
(loaded from file D:\a\krystal-bull\krystal-bull\src\main\resources\icons\krystal_bull.ico).
[21:10:46.560] Using default package resource WinLauncher.template [Template for creating executable properties file] (add krystalbull.properties to the resource-dir to customize).
[21:10:47.532] MSI ProductCode: c47093f7-318f-3c33-b6f9-e8a8c4adb014.
[21:10:47.533] MSI UpgradeCode: c62bde9b-3ba1-3197-8853-ba4770495959.
[21:10:47.536] Using default package resource main.wxs [Main WiX project file] (add main.wxs to the resource-dir to customize).
[21:10:47.537] Using default package resource overrides.wxi [Overrides WiX project file] (add overrides.wxi to the resource-dir to customize).
[21:10:47.540] Preparing MSI config: D:\a\krystal-bull\krystal-bull\krystalbull-0.1.msi.
[21:10:47.541] Generating MSI: D:\a\krystal-bull\krystal-bull\krystalbull-0.1.msi.
[21:10:47.552] Running C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\candle.exe in C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull
[21:10:50.004] Command:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\candle.exe -nologo C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\main.wxs -ext WixUtilExtension -arch x64 -out C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\wixobj\main.wixobj -dJpAppDescription=krystalbull -dJpAppVersion=0.1 -dJpProductCode=c47093f7-318f-3c33-b6f9-e8a8c4adb014 -dJpAppName=krystalbull -dJpAllowUpgrades=yes -dJpProductUpgradeCode=c62bde9b-3ba1-3197-8853-ba4770495959 -dJpIsSystemWide=yes -dJpAllowDowngrades=yes -dJpIcon=C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\krystalbull.exe -dJpAppVendor=Unknown -dJpConfigDir=C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config
[21:10:50.004] Output:
    main.wxs
[21:10:50.005] Returned: 0

[21:10:50.005] Running C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\candle.exe in C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull
[21:10:51.344] Command:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\candle.exe -nologo C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf -ext WixUtilExtension -arch x64 -out C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\wixobj\bundle.wixobj
[21:10:51.344] Output:
    bundle.wxf
[21:10:51.346] Returned: 0

[21:10:51.348] Running C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\light.exe in C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull
[21:10:53.013] Command:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\light.exe -nologo -spdb -ext WixUtilExtension -out D:\a\krystal-bull\krystal-bull\krystalbull-0.1.msi -sice:ICE27 -loc C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\MsiInstallerStrings_en.wxl -cultures:en-us C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\wixobj\main.wixobj C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\wixobj\bundle.wixobj
[21:10:53.015] Output:
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(41) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\FileMenu$anon$2.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(56) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\dialog\ViewEventDialog$anon$10$anon$21$anonfun$lessinit$greater$1.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(71) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\SettingsMenu$anon$5.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(111) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\dialog\ViewEventDialog$anon$4.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(116) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\home\HomePane$anon$4.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(151) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\home\HomePane$anon$28.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(206) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\dialog\CreateNumericEventDialog$anon$6.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(221) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\home\HomePane$anon$10$anon$16.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(226) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\landing\LandingPane$anon$5.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(236) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\dialog\ViewEventDialog$anon$10.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(256) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\dialog\ViewEventDialog$anon$10$anon$22.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(271) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\dialog\CreateEnumEventDialog$anon$12$anon$13$anon$14.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(301) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\TaskRunner$anon$1$anon$2.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(336) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\home\HomePane$anon$10$anon$11.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(356) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\dialog\ViewEventDialog$anon$10$anon$16.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(366) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\dialog\CreateNumericEventDialog$anon$4.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(391) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\ViewMenu$anon$9.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(411) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\dialog\CreateEnumEventDialog$anon$1.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(426) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\HelpMenu$anon$13.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(436) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\landing\LandingPane$anon$7.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(451) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\home\HomePane$anon$21.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(461) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\ViewMenu$anon$9$anon$10.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(476) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\home\HomePane$anon$2.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(531) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\home\HomePane$anon$10$anon$14.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(546) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\dialog\ViewEventDialog$anon$2.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(556) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\dialog\CreateEnumEventDialog$anon$12$anon$15$anon$17.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(561) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\home\HomePane$anon$17.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(596) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\GUI$anon$1.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(601) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\home\HomePane$anon$23.class'.
    C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\bundle.wxf(631) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull\app\classes\com\krystal\bull\gui\home\HomePane$anon$18.class'.
.. more of the same ..
[21:10:53.019] Returned: 103

[21:10:53.020] java.io.IOException: Command [C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\light.exe, -nologo, -spdb, -ext, WixUtilExtension, -out, D:\a\krystal-bull\krystal-bull\krystalbull-0.1.msi, -sice:ICE27, -loc, C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\MsiInstallerStrings_en.wxl, -cultures:en-us, C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\wixobj\main.wixobj, C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\wixobj\bundle.wixobj] in C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull exited with 103 code
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.Executor.executeExpectSuccess(Executor.java:91)
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.WixPipeline.execute(WixPipeline.java:135)
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.WixPipeline.buildMsi(WixPipeline.java:99)
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.WinMsiBundler.buildMSI(WinMsiBundler.java:521)
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.WinMsiBundler.execute(WinMsiBundler.java:386)
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.Arguments.generateBundle(Arguments.java:664)
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.Arguments.processArguments(Arguments.java:538)
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.main.Main.execute(Main.java:98)
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.main.Main.main(Main.java:52)
[21:10:53.512] jdk.jpackage.internal.PackagerException: java.io.IOException: Command [C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\light.exe, -nologo, -spdb, -ext, WixUtilExtension, -out, D:\a\krystal-bull\krystal-bull\krystalbull-0.1.msi, -sice:ICE27, -loc, C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\MsiInstallerStrings_en.wxl, -cultures:en-us, C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\wixobj\main.wixobj, C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\wixobj\bundle.wixobj] in C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull exited with 103 code
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.WinMsiBundler.execute(WinMsiBundler.java:389)
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.Arguments.generateBundle(Arguments.java:664)
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.Arguments.processArguments(Arguments.java:538)
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.main.Main.execute(Main.java:98)
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.main.Main.main(Main.java:52)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Command [C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\light.exe, -nologo, -spdb, -ext, WixUtilExtension, -out, D:\a\krystal-bull\krystal-bull\krystalbull-0.1.msi, -sice:ICE27, -loc, C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\MsiInstallerStrings_en.wxl, -cultures:en-us, C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\wixobj\main.wixobj, C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\wixobj\bundle.wixobj] in C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\images\win-msi.image\krystalbull exited with 103 code
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.Executor.executeExpectSuccess(Executor.java:91)
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.WixPipeline.execute(WixPipeline.java:135)
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.WixPipeline.buildMsi(WixPipeline.java:99)
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.WinMsiBundler.buildMSI(WinMsiBundler.java:521)
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.WinMsiBundler.execute(WinMsiBundler.java:386)
    ... 4 more
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Are you able to run the command `C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\light.exe -nologo -spdb -ext WixUtilExtension -out D:\a\krystal-bull\krystal-bull\krystalbull-0.1.msi -sice:ICE27 -loc C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\config\MsiInstallerStrings_en.wxl -cultures:en-us C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\wixobj\main.wixobj C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.jpackage17983400798231933520\wixobj\bundle.wixobj` manually and check if you get more details?

Comment: Also from the return code 103 of the `light.exe` this could be related to https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5314 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340386/wix-3-11-1-error-lght0103-the-system-cannot-find-the-file but this is only a guess

Comment: This is a bug in the jdk: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8282351

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this a bug in jpackage itself for windows

`jpackage` does not properly escape class file names for the WIX pre-processor.

See:

https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/6734

Bug tracker for the issue on openjdk:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8282351

Answer (score 0):

`jpackage` fails on Windows when application name differs from installer name as mentioned in the issue [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8254783)

It works for me if I specify the same argument to `--name` is I specified for the app image.

(The same name as for the app-image command, but you might want to change the name).

Comment: I tried this and tried to separate the generation of a `msi` and `app-image` and it still doesn't seem to work https://github.com/bitcoin-s/krystal-bull/runs/2657008254#step:8:1